# Java юнит-тесты и mock объектов DAO

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito

У меня есть такой DAO-класс, который я хочу покрыть юнит-тестами при помощи JUnit и Mockito:

```
public class CarFileLinkDAO extends CommonDAO {

    private static final String SELECT_IDENTIFIER = "select count(*) from car_file_links where car_number = ? and inv_number = ?";
    private static final String INSERT_RECORD = "insert into car_file_links(creator_id, sys_id, car_number, inv_number, file_creator, file_sys_id)"
            + "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    public boolean wagonIdentifierExists(String carNumber, String invNumber) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_IDENTIFIER);
            ps.setString(1, carNumber);
            ps.setString(2, invNumber);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getInt(1) != 0;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null && !rs.isClosed()) {
                    rs.close();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored) {}

            try {
                if (ps != null && !ps.isClosed()) {
                    ps.close();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored) {}
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean insertDocument(Document doc) {
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_RECORD);
            ps.setString(1, doc.getString("creatorId"));
            ps.setString(2, doc.getString("sysId"));
            ps.setString(3, doc.getString("carNumber"));
            ps.setString(4, doc.getString("invNumber"));
            ps.setString(5, doc.getString("fileCreator"));
            ps.setString(6, doc.getString("fileSysId"));
            ps.executeUpdate();

            return true;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Для тестирования методов DAO я создал такой класс:

```
package pg.dao;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class CarFileLinkDAOTest {

    private CarFileLinkDAO dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        dao = mock(CarFileLinkDAO.class);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void wagonIdentifierExists() {
        Document doc = new Document()
                .append("creatorId", "a")
                .append("sysId", "b")
                .append("carNumber", "c")
                .append("invNumber", "d")
                .append("fileCreator", "e")
                .append("fileSysId", "f");
        dao.insertDocument(doc);
        when(dao.wagonIdentifierExists("c", "d")).thenReturn(true);
        when(dao.wagonIdentifierExists("not", "exists")).thenReturn(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void insertDocument() {
        Document doc = new Document()
                .append("creatorId", "a")
                .append("sysId", "b")
                .append("carNumber", "c")
                .append("invNumber", "d")
                .append("fileCreator", "e")
                .append("fileSysId", "f");
        when(dao.insertDocument(doc)).thenReturn(true);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что эти тесты выполняются верно всегда, даже если я подставляю в функции неправильные параметры или ожидаю неправильный результат. Как надо писать тесты для мокнутых объектов?

Comment: с тестированием я познакомился прямо как вы вот-вот и мокито узнал буквально вчера, как я понимаю, тестировать нужно результат работы.. например, берем wagonIdentifierExists(), задаемся вопросом, что он делает ? очевидно, что он создает prepareStatement, вот правильность его создания и нужно проверить, если вообще хотите что-то проверять.. если текущий код не позволяет это протестировать, то видоизмените его так, чтобы логика работы не изменилась, но стало возможным проверить, то что он делает.. взяв второй метод insertDocument(), поймете, что он аналогичен первому в смысле результата..

Answer (score 1):

Вам не следует mock'ать объект, который тестируете.

Если Вы тестируете объект, методы которого зависят от другим объектов, то именно эти другие объекты должны быть mock'ами. Скорей всего Вы можете создать mock для `Connection` (который получаете из `getConnection()`), но смысла в этом мало. На мой взгляд лучше запускать тесты на тестовой БД.